# wrap tag text up to certain character javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have an auto generated list in PHP.

How do I wrap a span tag around characters up to and including the dash?  I want to be able to change the number and the dash with css.  I want to target all of the list items.

```
Eg:
1-Item
2-Item
3-Item
  1-SubItem
  2-SubItem
4-Item
```

Comment: I think you should do using PHP... can you share your PHP code...

Comment: do in your php code itself as echo "<ul><li>Item1</li></ul>";

Comment: `preg_replace('/^(\d+-)/', '<span>$1</span>', $value)` - a simple replace in PHP does the trick

Comment: The issue I'm having is because it's part of a plugin in Wordpress, I don't feel comfortable modifying the code...

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
ul {
    counter-reset: item;
}
li {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: .5em;
    margin-left: 2em;
}
li:before {
    display: inline-block;
    content: counter(item) "- ";
    counter-increment: item;
    width: 2em;
    margin-left: -2em;
}
```

Check out the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/3oho2t7v/